# how to parseFloat this?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have this code :

```
$wage = array();
foreach ($result3 as $row3) {
  $wage[] = '[' . floatval($row3['age']) . ',' . floatval($row3['point']) .']';
}
if ($userid == 0 ) {
  $age= "";
} else {
  $age = implode(',', $wage).",";
}
 echo json_encode("var2"=>$myvar ,"var3"=>$age));  // i didnt write var2 because is same as var3
```

the above will outputs something like `[4,2.3][5,6],[1.7,5],`

and in javascript im receiving this value outputed above via ajax which has name `var3`.

```
dataType: 'json' ,
success: function(response){
var age = response['var3'] ; 
.....
```

so the question is how can i `parseFloat` this variable `age`  ?

EDIT .
if i alert the json like that

```
   alert (response);
```

i get  `[object Object]`   // make attention to small o and big O

EDIT2 .
used consol log

and i get this

```
  {"var2":"[2,5],[3.5,5],[6.5,6.5],[8,7],","var3":"[2,46],[3.5,61],[6.5,70],[8,71],","var4":"[2,32],[3.5,41],[6.5,42],[8,43],","var5":"[46,5],[61,5],[70,6.5],[71,7],"}
```

this returned values i want to `parseFloat` them as you see they are like strings between two quotes

Comment: You should use JSON (`json_encode()`) rather manually build JS code.

Comment: im using json encode i will edit my post

Comment: Please post the exact JSON output you're getting.

Comment: You should be using `json_encode()` for the whole thing, not just the last step.

Comment: alert wont be as helpful with objects as `console.log` will. Trying logging it to the console and hitting F12 (in FF and chrome) to see what log message you get

Comment: That is not the JSON you get for that.  Please copy and paste the real thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
$wage[] = '[' . floatval($row3['age']) . ',' . floatval($row3['point']) .']';
```

You're building a string, which coincidentally happens to LOOK like a javascript array definition, but it's still just a string. When this gets json_encoded, it'll come out as

```
"[...,...]"
^--       ^-- string
```

You need to build **NATIVE** data structures at all stages while in PHP, e.g.

```
$wage[] = array(floatval($row3['age']), floatval($row3['point']));
```

and not this mish-mash of native AND "json-like" strings. json_encode() converts **NATIVE** datatypes of the equivalent Javascript types. Since your own floatval business is producing a string, you'll get a json-encoded string, not an array.

Comment: have used your suggestion and i got this in console `{"var2":"Array,Array,Array,","var3":"[2,46],[3.5,61],[8,71],","var4":"[2,32],[3.5,41],[8,43],","var5":"[46,5],[61,5],[71,7],"}` as you see its array array array

Comment: because you're doing `implode()` on a multi-dimensional array. implode doesn't work on the extra dimensions.

Comment: so ! what will replace the implode then ? to build this result

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this all wrong. You do not need to do this;

```
foreach ($result3 as $row3) {
  $wage[] = '[' . floatval($row3['age']) . ',' . floatval($row3['point']) .']';
}
```

Perhaps what you want is;

```
foreach ($result3 as $i => $row3) {
  $newRow = $row3;
  $newRow['age'] = intval($row3['age']);
  $newRow['point'] = floatval($row3['point']);
  $result3[$i] = $newRow;
}
```

And then do this;

```
// Create JSON data, assuming that $result3 is an array
$jsonData = json_encode($result3);

// This will give you a JSON string, output this and finish to ensure it IS the only thing output
echo $jsonData;
die;
```

Now in your javascript, open the development console in what ever browser your using and use the following code in javascript

```
console.log(response)
```

This will output the whole `response` variable to the console and enable you to debug how to get specific data out of the `response` var.

Hope that helps.

Comment: u said it will give me JSON string , but my question is to get the returned value parseFloated not as string